# redux Actions must be plain objects but I defined plain object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I use **redux** + **react** to build my website, and I want to use redux to control a sidebar visible.The sidebar is defined by semantic-ui-react.Because I want to control it across another component, so I defined the **props** in sidebar's parent component `const { visible, dispatch } = this.props`, there is a **onClick** function to handle this. I will show my code.

> Uncaught Error: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions.

This error confused me one afternoon, and I don't know why! This is my action code:

```
**action**

export const SIDEBARISVISIBLE = 'sidebarVisible'

export function sidebarVisibleAction() {
  return { type: SIDEBARISVISIBLE }
}
```

As you can see, I defined an action creator returned a plain object.

And this is my reducer code:

```
**reducer**

import SIDEBARISVISIBLE from '../actions/outside.js'

function sidebarVisible(state = {
  sidebarIsVisible: false
}, action) {

    switch (action.type) {
        case SIDEBARISVISIBLE:
            return Object.assign({}, state, {
                sidebarIsVisible: !state.sidebarIsVisible
            })
        default:
            return state
    }
}

export default sidebarVisible
```

Also my store code:

```
**store**

import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
import sidebarVisible from '../reducers/outside.js'

export default initialState => {
  return createStore(
    sidebarVisible,
    initialState,
    applyMiddleware(thunk)
  )
}
```

Then, my component code(part of):

```
class OutsideView extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = { activeItem: '' }
    }

    handleItemClick = (e, { name }) => this.setState({ activeItem: name })

    render() {
        const { activeItem } = this.state
        const { visible, dispatch } = this.props

        return (
            <div>
                <SidebarNav visible={ visible } />

                ......

                   <Menu.Item
                    name='sidebar'
                    active={ activeItem === 'sidebar'}
                    onClick={ (e, {name}) => {
                                this.setState({ activeItem: name })
                                dispatch(sidebarVisibleAction)
                            } }>
                    <Icon color='red' name='list' />
                </Menu.Item>

OutsideView.PropTypes = {
    visible: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
    dispatch: PropTypes.func.isRequired
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    visible: state.sidebarIsVisible,
  }
}

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps
)(OutsideView)
```

The last, my Router:

```
import configureStore from './store/index.js'
const store = configureStore()

export default class Root extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <Provider store={ store }>
            <Router history={ browserHistory }>
                <Route path="/" component={ OutsideRedux }>
                    <Route path='register' component={ Register } />
                    <Route path='login' component={ Login } />
                    <Route path='blog' component={ Blog } />
                    <Route path='about' component={ About } />
                    <Route path='home' component={ Home } />
                    <Route path='ask' component={ Ask } />
                    <Route path='panel' component={ Panel } />
                    <Route path='setting' component={ Setting } />
                    <Route path='user' component={ User } />
                </Route>
            </Router>
            </Provider>
        )
    }
}
```

So, I search for answer for this error, most of them say, you have to setup redux-thunk and with **ApplyMiddleware** to use it, the simplest way.But the action I defined is **plain object**.If I don't use redux-thunk, I think I will not encounter this error either.So, I'm very confused, how to solve this?

Thanks for all the help

Comment: Not sure that's related, therefore I'm writing this as a comment. Why are you using `dispatch`? You should use `mapDispatchToProps ` in [`connect`](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connectmapstatetoprops-mapdispatchtoprops-mergeprops-options) and get the action as `this.props.actionName`. Just make sure you use the props version and not the imported one. Made this mistake too many times :D

Comment: Also a general comment about your code, why use component state if you're already using redux? If you're using redux, it's best to do all all state management via redux, the code is easier to reason about and more simple to test. An extra bonus is that this way, you don't need class, you can use pure component.

Comment: @MarkoGrešak Yes, I will explain about you said.First, I use **dispatch**, because I refer to the official redux Reddit API code.Second, the state I use is just for active an item, this is semantic-ui-react default achieve, so I am not change it.

Comment: Except some very basic examples, I haven't used `dispatch` in my code, therefore I failed to see the error, but @nobody found the answer. But what I suggested would still work, because `mapDispatchToProps` warps the action as dispatch call, so you can use the action as regular function and omit the `dispatch(action(args))` syntax in favor of, in my opinion, more clean `action(args)` call.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Here:

`dispatch(sidebarVisibleAction)`

you are passing function `sidebarVisibleAction` to `dispach`. You should call it and pass result, so the code will look like:

`dispatch(sidebarVisibleAction())`

(now `dispatch` will get object, not a function).

Comment: Great catch. I was looking at this when in search of an answer, but somehow missed it. To the author (who mentioned they are referring to official Reddit API example), this can be seen used here: http://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/ExampleRedditAPI.html#containersasyncappjs

Comment: Yes, it's the answer! Thank you! But I change my code I found a new error: (0 , _outside2.default) is not a function.And thanks for @MarkoGrešak, I think you are right, I change my code to use **mapDispatchToProps** and connect it. I'm trying to solve new error.

Comment: @g1eny0ung this looks like wrong use of `import` and/or `export`. It's hard to tell where, because you don't seem to have included all the code. If you don't figure it out yourself, post a new question.

Comment: @MarkoGrešak Yes, you're right. The reducer code's **import** is wrong, I should use {} to bracket SIDEBARISVISIBLE. Thank you very much and thanks also @ nobody.English is not my native, so I only know "Thank you",
This kind of gratitude(This sentence use translator, haha)

Comment: perfect answer with explanation for beginners like me :) +1